# Does immutability improve GC performance in lazily evaluated languages?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Intuitively, given that lazy-evaluated thunks can contain cycles and are updated concurrently with garbage collection, this doesn't look much different than GC for mutable data - except maybe that pointers need to be traversed only once, evaluated or rewritten during compaction pause.

Does the claim in [Haskell wiki book](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Memory_Management) correctly identify benefits of having immutable (lazily evaluated) data on the heap?

Does the algorithm prevent sharing commonly reduced values (like small integers or strings) at runtime causing more data to be kept and copied around?

Answer (score 2):

That page in the wikibook contains a link to an accurate description of GHC's garbage collector and the logic behind it (http://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/parallel-gc.pdf); by one of the people who actually wrote it.

GHC uses a generational garbage collector. It doesn't traverse every object in every garbage collection phase, but splits the heap into 3 "generations" numbered 0, 1, and 2. When objects are created they are initially placed in generation 0; which is traversed every time the garbage collector is run. If an object survives a few rounds of garbage collection it's assumed to be a long-lived object and is promoted to the next generation up; which is checked less frequently. When an object A has an immutable reference to object B: this means B will need to exist at least as long as A, so the garbage collector also promotes B.

Because of lazy evaluation: the claim in the wikibook that "immutable data NEVER points to younger values" is actually wrong; but immutability does help the garbage collector by helping it estimate the lifetimes of heap objects.

Comment: As I understand it, the way laziness is handled is that when something in an old generation is alive and has a child evaluated, the child allocates in the same generation as its parent. I could be off, but it would make that claim true.

Comment: That would make sense